# How do I catch an error due to wrong latitude or longitude in Bing Maps V8 Web Control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, bing-maps

At the moment I'm working on a project in which I'm supposed to show various customers worldwide on a map. I determine the coordinates of these customers using the Bing Maps API. But if I then want to display these customers on the map, I get the error for some that the coordinates are wrong. The coordinates in the database look correct and are returned to me by the Bing Maps API.

Now to the question:
How do I catch this error so that the script doesn't crash because of it?

```
let map;
let searchManager;
let customers = <?= json_encode($elements); ?>;
let pins = [];
let iconURL = '';

function GetMap() {
    var statusDropdownValue = parseInt($('#status').val());

    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#map', {
        zoom: 1
    });

    $.each(customers, function(index, value) {
        var customerLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(value['latitude'], value['longitude']);

        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(customerLocation, {
            icon: baseURL + 'assets/images/pin.png'
        });

        pin.metadata = {
            id: value['id'],
            customerName: value['customer_name'],
            postCode: value['post_code'],
            city: value['city'],
            countryCode: value['country_code']
        };

        pins.push(pin);
    });

    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Clustering", function () {
        clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(pins);
        map.layers.insert(clusterLayer);
    });

    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.AutoSuggest', function () {
        var manager = new Microsoft.Maps.AutosuggestManager({ map: map });
        manager.attachAutosuggest('#search', '#search-container-search-bar', selectedSuggestion);
    });
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid latitude
n https://r.bing.com/rp/iKR9c24bDSIz79-enVSnBoJvZx8.br.js:1
GetMap http://localhost/projects/BattermannTillery_HK_Locator/maps:101
each jQuery
GetMap http://localhost/projects/BattermannTillery_HK_Locator/maps:100
notifyMapReadyForBootstrap https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&setMkt=en-US&setLang=en&key=AlV57vXOvuSENqgwu6hnNKGhiLf85dbTMlnDY81z2cGq40L1xkMdXUVSkEhvqfvv:12
<anonymous> https://r.bing.com/rp/RENSVX2edu6CiHiu-aMi-GbtqbA.br.js:1
<anonymous> https://r.bing.com/rp/RENSVX2edu6CiHiu-aMi-GbtqbA.br.js:1
```

Comment: Uncaught Error:Invalid latitude
    n https://r.bing.com/rp/iKR9c24bDSIz79-enVSnBoJvZx8.br.js:1
    GetMap http://localhost/projects/BattermannTillery_HK_Locator/maps:101
    each jQuery
    GetMap http://localhost/projects/BattermannTillery_HK_Locator/maps:100
    notifyMapReadyForBootstrap https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&setMkt=en-US&setLang=en&key=AlV57vXOvuSENqgwu6hnNKGhiLf85dbTMlnDY81z2cGq40L1xkMdXUVSkEhvqfvv:12
    <anonymous> https://r.bing.com/rp/RENSVX2edu6CiHiu-aMi-GbtqbA.br.js:1
    <anonymous> https://r.bing.com/rp/RENSVX2edu6CiHiu-aMi-GbtqbA.br.js:1

Comment: Please add the error you are facing to the question, along with more details. Why is this question tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question when you have more details, not put it into comments. This isn't a forum. See also [ask] and the [tour] to learn more about stackoverflow and how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Well, wouldn't it be a good start to check if `value['latitude']` and `value['longitude']` are numbers, and if not, ignore the customer?

Comment: My bad! I added the error to the question and since I get the coordinates out of the database via PHP I added the PHP tag. Latitude and Longitude are numbers and they're looking like coordinates should look like.

Comment: Well, the error implies some latitude is not valid.

Comment: That's right, but I can't verify several thousand coordinates for accuracy, so I just want to query for the error and let the script continue.

Comment: So what's stopping you doing what AKX suggested then? i.e. writing code to check the values at least contain numbers before trying to process that item

Comment: But if that's not really the issue and you simply want to catch the bing error after the fact, I'd expect you can use a try/catch block

Comment: I tried that, but then the whole script hangs.

Comment: Really? Catch should allow you to continue. Maybe edit the question to show us exactly what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following to debug this issue:

1. Open dev console in browser, add a break point where you create the `Location` object. Check to see if `value['latitude']` is a string number or an actual number ("1" vs 1). If it is a string, wrap `value['latitude']`, `value['longitude']` with `parseFloat` like `(parseFloat(value['latitude'])`. This is the most common cause of this type of error.
2. If the above doesn't solve your issue, it would be best to check your data (I'm assuming you have the coordinates stored somewhere). Double check you haven't reversed `latitude` and `longitude` values (take a couple of entries and manually search for them on bing.com/maps and check the coordinates to verify what you have in your lat/lon columns is in the same general area). If you can query your dataset (is it a database?), you can check all latitude and longitude values. Latitude values should be between -90 and 90 degrees, and longitude between -180 and 180. If you find anything outside of this range it will be either due to bad data, or you have latitude/longitude values swapped in your data.